# Cannot Find Column when filtering

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I am using vb.net to try and fill a combobox with values from my MySQL database which works fine by inserting the code below:

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT distinct Department FROM users"
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connectionString)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "users")
            With Find_Dep
                .Items.Add("Select")
                .DisplayMember = "Department"
                .ValueMember = "Department"
                .DataSource = ds.Tables("users")
                .SelectedIndex = 0
            End With
```

I have three two queries which rely on TextBoxes to search my DataGrid which also work fine. I am trying to use the current code to allow my ComboBox to grab the values from MySQL and filter them specific values from the datagrid:

```
Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet1)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("[Department] Like '%" & Find_Dep.Text & "%'")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
```

This code above works fine if i manually add the pre-defined values into the ComboBox without populating the ComboBox from MySQL. So there is a conflict between the two and i cant figure out what it is as i am new to VB.
Retrieving error message: .Cannot Find Column[Department]' upon adding both chunks of code above. Whats the conflict?
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "Department" has to be a column used in the dbDataSet1 query.  Department is not a mySQL reserved word, so you dont need to escape it, and if the CBO has the actual Departments in it, you dont need LIKE

Comment: Your not using `String.Format` correctly here. It inserts parameters in placeholders.

Comment: `String.Format("Department Like '%{0}%'", Find_Dep.Text)`

Comment: What is with the down vote... Is my question not explained well. I thought i provided all the necessary information which allowed me to solve my problem. Why down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix your quotes. Opened and closed.Number of quotes must be even.

Comment: Cheers this solved it and the fact that i used two commands at the same time.